Get file from azure blob storage in airflow - No such file or directory
I'm trying to get a file from Azure Blob Storage. But it doesn't find the directory or file when I pass the path_file parameter.
I'm trying to use this function to get a file from my azure blob storage.
(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/wasb/index.html)
doc
The code I'm using is, and I am passing the apis/ value in the file_path parameter.
Function
I checked my blob on the Azure portal and removed it from here to pass the file_path parameter.
View when agent clicks on file in azure blob storage.
out put log airflow
My file is in this path: (My container name is 'airflow')
/airflow/apis/file.py
My attempts pass the file_path parameter:
/home/airflow/apis/file.py
/opt/airflow/apis/file.py
/airflow/apis/file.py
I don't know if I'm missing a root in my path.

The container name would not be included in the path (depends on the library you use)
if your absolute path is '/airflow/apis/file.py' then generally,
container name: 'airflow'
path: 'apis/file.py'
below is a code sample to download and upload a file to blob via azure-python sdk
import os
import time
import json
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient # type: ignore
import uuid
from random import randrange
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential # type: ignore
import traceback
import datetime as dt
from io import BytesIO


BLOB_CONNECTION_STR = "Connection string here"
CONTAINER = "Name of container" #eg 'mycontainer'
PATH_TO_FILE = "path to file after container" #eg 'data/folder1/file.json'

class BlobHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        base class for azure file helper
        """
        self.blob_service_client = None
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.blob_service_client = self.get_container_client()

    def get_container_client(self):
        """
        get client object for azure blob and sets class member
        """
        try:
            manage_identity = MANAGE_IDENTITY
            if str(manage_identity).lower() == 'true':
                manage_identity = True
            else:
                manage_identity = False
        except:
            manage_identity = False

    def download_blob_to_stream(self, container_name, coredata_path):
        """
        download blob data to i/o stream
        Args:
            container_name: name of container
            coredata_path: absolute path from container to blob file

        Returns:
            bytes io
        """
        try:
            blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=coredata_path)
            res = blob_client.download_blob()
            return res
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return False

    def upload_blob_data(self, container_name, data, blobname):
        """
        upload json data to azure blob
        Args:
            container_name: name of blob container name
            data: json string data
            blobname: name of azure blob file
        """
        blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blobname)
        res = blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite=True)
        print("Done..", res)
        return res


blob_object = BlobHelper()
res = blob_object.download_blob_to_stream(CONTAINER,PATH_TO_FILE)
if res:
    res = res.readall().decode("utf-8")
    print(json.loads(res))

